# if i call the erase function(for leading whitespace) first in a program to trim whitespaces , the function call for the trailing whitespace is ignored

Tags: c++

```
// lecture 15: program to trim the start and end white spaces from a string object.

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// function signature:
void trim(std::string*);

// main body:
int main() {
    std::string cast = "            pokemon legends , arceus               "; //input string
    trim(&cast);
    return 0;
}

void trim(std::string* x) {
    int s = 0; // start index 
    int size = (*x).size();
    int e = size - 1; // end index
    //start whitespace terminator
    while (s < size && ((*x)[s] == ' ' || (*x)[s] == '\t' || (*x)[s] == '\n')) {     // x[s] returns a char      therefore we should not compare with "" string type.
        s++;
    }
    //end whitespace terminator
    while (e > s && (*x)[e] == ' ' || (*x)[e] == '\t' || (*x)[e] == '\n') {
        e--;
    }

    (*x).erase(0, s);       // if I call this first ,the second call is ignored. But the program runs   fine if it is called after the trailing whitespace erase.
    (*x).erase(e + 1);       //NOTE:: the order of these two functions is important for trimming  whitespaces ??????????/learn why. also putting them inside the while loop create some errors ,check why .

    std::cout << "ok" + *x + "ok" << std::endl;
}
```

I tried to call the leading whitespace erase function( referring to .erase ) first but it results in  some error .

I tried looking up the problem on chatgpt but it doesn't solve or understand my problem or my question.

Comment: Why are you passing a *pointer* to the string, instead of a reference?

Comment: Instead of `std::cout <<"ok"+*x+"ok"<< std::endl;`, why not `std::cout << "ok" << *x << "ok" << std::endl;`?

Comment: Side-note: your _"end whitespace terminator"_ loop does not use the same logic as the previous loop, and this looks like a bug. It can happily rewind `e` to be less than `s` in the case where your string consists entirely of whitespace and the first character is not a space. You might not want that.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has a pretty basic explanation.

As soon as you trim the whitespace from the beginning of the string, the index where whitespace starts at the end changes. You are calculating the space at the end too early.  Or, easier just reverse how they are called:

```
'    string   '
```

Given the above, the whitespace at the end is at index 10.
But, as soon as you trim the beginning, it is at index 6.